# Do any commentators told about interpolation of puranas?

Tags: puranas, interpolation, commentary

Commentators told about interpolation in Puranas

Which Purana do commentators takes as authentic ?
Do any commentators list interpolation puranas ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are all the 18 paurāṇika literature authentic?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/46510/are-all-the-18-paur%c4%81%e1%b9%87ika-literature-authentic)

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: How it is Duplicate

Comment: I am talking about Purana and commentator